# Тестирование void методов с помощью JUnit

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, тестирование, junit

Есть класс , который выполняет деление столбиком и результат отображает графически выводом в консоль. Как протестировать такой метод?

```
public class IntegerDivision {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
IntegerDivision integerDivision = new IntegerDivision();

try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));) {

    int dividend = integerDivision.read(reader);
    int divider = 0;
    int attempNumber = 0;

    while (divider == 0) {

    if (attempNumber != 0) {
        System.out.println("Сan not be divided into zero");
    }

    divider = integerDivision.read(reader);
    }      

    integerDivision.divide(dividend, divider);
}
}

public void divide(int dividend, int divider) {

    int lineCount = 1;
    int result = 0;
    int dividendRemainder = 0;
    int elementCount = 0;
    int dividendPart = 0;
    int subtractedDigit = 0;

    System.out.println("_" + dividend + " | " + divider);
    lineCount++;

    String dividendString = String.valueOf(dividend);
    String[] dividendDigits = dividendString.split("");

    while (elementCount < dividendDigits.length) {

        if (elementCount == 0) {
            dividendPart = Integer.parseInt(dividendDigits[elementCount]);
        } else {
            dividendPart = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dividendPart) + dividendDigits[elementCount]);
        }

        if (dividendPart >= divider) {
            result = dividendPart / divider;
            dividendRemainder = dividendPart % divider;
            subtractedDigit = result * divider;

            if (lineCount == 2) {
                display(dividend, divider, lineCount);

            } else {
                display(dividendPart, subtractedDigit, lineCount);
            }

            dividendPart = dividendRemainder;
            lineCount++;
            elementCount++;

        } else {
            elementCount++;
        }
    }

    lineCount = 0;
    display(dividend, dividendRemainder, lineCount);    
}
/* Выводит результат в консоль в виде
    78945|4
    4    |------
    -----|19736
    38
    36
     29
     28
      14
      12
       25
       24
        1*/
public void display(int firstNumber, int secondNumber, int lineNumber) {
   ...............
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}

public  int count(int number) {
    ........
    return numberString.length();
}

public String collect(int symbolsNumber, char symbol) {
   ........
    return string.toString();
}

private int read(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
.......
return Integer.parseInt(readedLine);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как протестировать такой метод?

Никак. Можно, конечно, прибегать к локальным хитростям (см. соседний ответ), но это далеко не всегда поможет. В первую очередь код нужно писать таким образом, чтобы он легко тестировался. Юнит-тесты должны тестировать код, который не связан с внешним миром (в данном случае это консоль). Как этого добиться в вашем случае? Разделить [ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8): подсчетом должна заниматься одна часть кода, выводом -- другая часть кода.

Например, метод `divide()` может возвращать коллекцию объектов вида `<int firstNumber, int secondNumber, int lineNumber>` -- именно тех значений, которые вы используете для того, чтобы выводить результаты на экран. В методе `divide()` должна остаться только логика. И тогда код разделится на две части -- вычисление и вывод (псевдокод, точный синтаксис Джавы я уже плохо помню):

```
var data = integerDivision.divide(dividend, divider);

display(dividend, dividendRemainder, 0);
System.out.println("_" + dividend + " | " + divider);
foreach (var item in data) {
    display(item.FirstNumber, item.SecondNumber, item.LineNumber);
}
```

Теперь и протестировать метод `divide()` станет проще простого (снова псевдокод):

```
public void test()
{
    IntegerDivision integerDivision = new IntegerDivision();

    var data = integerDivision.divide(4, 4);

    assertAreEqual(1, data.Length);
    assertAreEqual(..., data[0].FirstNumber);
    assertAreEqual(..., data[0].SecondNumber);
    assertAreEqual(..., data[0].LineNumber);
}
```

Можно пойти еще дальше, и разделить в методе `divide()` собственно математику и форматирование результатов (`lineCount`).

Answer (score 3):

Переменная out в классе System статичная, поэтому перед запуском теста можно подменить поток вывода в консоль на свой:

```
 protected final ByteArrayOutputStream output;
 private PrintStream old;

 @Before
 public void setUpStreams() {
  old = System.out;
  output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(output));
 }

 @After
 public void cleanUpStreams() {
  System.setOut(old);
 }


 @Test
 public void testString() {
  IntegerDivision division = new IntegerDivision();
  division.divide(17.0, 23.0);
  String template = "ожидаемый вывод в консоль";
  Assert.assertEquals(template, output.toString());
 }
```